# aspnet core how to webpack build on deploy

Tags: webpack, asp.net-core, gulp, vue.js, visual-studio-2017

I have a aspnet core application with a vue.js part, which I build with webpack and everything works fine.
Now I search a solution to create a productionbuild with it, to create a minified version of my vue bundle and to run vue in production mode (without console.logs), which I set in my `webpack.config` like:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    module.exports.plugins = [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: '"production"'
            }
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            }
        })
    ]
} else {
    module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
}
```

but `process.env.NODE_ENV` is always undefined when I webpack it via gulp.
Than I tried to use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices` with this line in `startup.cs`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
...
    if(env.IsDevelopment())
        app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware();
...
}
```

This works also fine like my gulp configuration and `process.env.NODE_ENV` property is set to `'development'`

Now I try to create a production build in VS 2017 (Build -> Publish Projectname), but no webpack task runs.

So i tried to add this in my *.csproj:

```
<Target Name="PrepublishScript" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
    <Exec Command="npm run build" />
</Target>
```

this throws the error: The command "npm run build" exited with code 1.

Now I'm out of other ideas to resolve it and hope that anyone can help me. THX!

Comment: The build output will usually give you a little more information than just `exited with code 1`. What is causing the npm command to fail?

Comment: `npm ERR! missing script: build` and if I try tu use command `gulp min` I get these error:

Comment: \node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:15
      throw new Error(errors.missingBinary());
      ^

EXEC(0,0): Error : Missing binding \node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-48\binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Node.js 6.x
Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Windows 64-bit with Node.js 5.x
This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to build the binding for your current environment.

Comment: Yep, just needed to run the npm install.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Resolved using:
in `.csproj`:

```
<Target Name="PrepublishScript" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
    <Exec Command="npm install" />
    <Exec Command="npm run production" />
</Target>
```

and adding scripts in my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --hide-modules",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --hide-modules"
}
```

this needs `webpack` & `cross-env` packages (and all other used packages during webpack) installed & a working `webpack.config.js`

Ask if someone is interrested to my `webpack.config.js` or some other code

Comment: cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config .... is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.