# How to determine whether the web app is running in development or production mode?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am running a vuejs application inside ASP.NET app using visual studio. I am using webpack and have followed this tutorial for setup : https://marczak.io/posts/netcore-vuejs/. I am unable to figure out how to run the app on production mode? If I need to change my process.env.NODE_ENV, from where shall I change it?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the mode that the app is running by `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

However you can't access it directly to the template since it's scoped by Vue's `this` context.

If you want to access it in the Vue template you can do it with a computed property.

```
computed: {
 appMode () {
   return process.env.NODE_ENV
 }
}
```

And in the template:

```
<p> {{ appMode }} </p>
```

I highly recommend you to learn more [here (Vue CLI Docs)](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes-and-environment-variables)

> You have to be aware that when you are ready to deploy your
>   application you can set the modes. For example I suggest you to add 2
>   scripts in `package.json`:

```
scripts: {
   // other scripts
    "build-production": "vue-cli-service build --mode production",
    "build-staging": "vue-cli-service build --mode staging",
}
```

**When you want to deploy to staging run:**

> `npm run build-staging`

**When you want to deploy to production run:**

> `npm run build-production`

Comment: This doesn't work. It gives an error cannot read property 'env' of undefined. I know it could have happened with the help of scripts but, it's visual studio and here I am directly running my app.Hence I am unable to figure it out

Comment: Maybe checkout this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122177/aspnet-core-how-to-webpack-build-on-deploy

Comment: This doesn't matter too as I am not using cli. I am directly running via IIS Express.